# session management in rails without User model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication

I have an rails app which relies on authenticating username/password entered to an external webservice. Rails app will not have a user model. When a user enters login/password and it makes a post request to check that login/password. External application will return back a cookie or token which can be used for subsequent requests made from rails app.

There is no User model in the rails app since all the users are stored in an external application.

Is there a gem which let me strictly do session management? I'm planning on storing that token in a session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not just create a sessions controller that saves the token into a session? I don't see a need for a gem.

something like

```
sessions[:token] = token
```

If you are dealing with a tokens that expire like facebook you can take a look at this

http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2011/05/13/how-to--handle-expired-access-tokens/

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I might look at the way Michael Hartl does user sessions in his Rails tutorial. What you want is something slightly different, but you might be able to reuse some of what he did there. http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-in-sign-out#sec-current_user

(It's also just a good tutorial to go through, regardless of your level of Rails experience.)